# cmd command from java application error

Tags: java, cmd

Recently I added "adb devices" in the nano ./bash_profile so that I can run it from any directory.
I used one java application to run

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    executeCmd("adb devices");

}

private static void executeCmd(String string) {
    InputStream pipedOut = null;
    try {
        Process aProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string);

        // These two thread shall stop by themself when the process end
        Thread pipeThread = new Thread(new StreamGobber(aProcess.getInputStream()));
        Thread errorThread = new Thread(new StreamGobber(aProcess.getErrorStream()));

        pipeThread.start();
        errorThread.start();

        aProcess.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class StreamGobber implements Runnable {

private InputStream Pipe;

public StreamGobber(InputStream pipe) {
    if(pipe == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("bad pipe");
    }
    Pipe = pipe;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        byte buffer[] = new byte[2048];

        int read = Pipe.read(buffer);
        while(read >= 0) {
            System.out.write(buffer, 0, read);

            read = Pipe.read(buffer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(Pipe != null) {
            try {
                Pipe.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

when I run any other commands such as "ls" it's working fine!!
I'm using mac ..

thanks :)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: did you check without your java application on the terminal if you can run the command ? And also specify which error you get / what the application does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Hi unverschaemt, yeah I checked it and it's running and listing the available devices in the terminal. this is the errors i get:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1042)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
 at Execution.executeCmd(Execution.java:44)
 at Execution.main(Execution.java:37)

Comment: You've added this to your .bash_profile, but java isn't actually executing this command using bash.

Comment: how is it executed ? I tried put it as ./adb devices but also the same error.. I tired this one also "/Volumes/development/android-sdk-macosx/tools dab devices" there is no error here but no result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe global path problem on mac. You can try run with absolute adb program path as command.

Comment: do you mean putting: Process aProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /Volumes/development/android-sdk-macosx/tools adb devices"); ???

Comment: without cd. I don have mac but on linux I will use something like this: "/opt/mydevtools/android-sdk/tools/bin/adb", its just example path I don't remember where adb execute bin file is.

Comment: I tried it without cd and there is no error but no result and response. devices are connected and appear in the terminal.

Comment: Maybe try divide command string into command and parameter and use as array like this: String[] string = {"/opt/mydevtools/android-sdk/tools/bin/adb", "devices"} and then Runtime.getRuntime().exec(string);